# PandocでMarkdownからPDFを生成する際のイメージへのパスが「Could not find image」となる問題について

Tags: markdown, pandoc

### 現状の問題

Pandocを利用してMarkdownで書かれたファイルをPDFに変換しようとしています。
現在、Markdownのファイルは下記のようなフォルダ構成で配置しています。

```
root/
 +- images/
      +- test.png
 +- docs/
      +- doc1.md
```

doc1.mdのファイル内容は下記のようになっています。

```
# テストドキュメント

![テストイメージ](../images/test.png)
```

上記のような構成で、rootフォルダ上で下記のコマンドを実行します。

```
pandoc docs/doc1.md -o doc1.pdf -V documentclass=ltjarticle --latex-engine=lualatex
```

すると、下記のエラーが発生してしまいます。

```
pandoc.exe: Could not find image `../images/test.png', skipping...
```

イメージのパスを`./images/test.png`とすれば正常に出力されることはわかっているのですが、doc1.mdはHTMLとしても表示したいため、doc1.mdファイル内のイメージへのパスを書き換えることなくPDFへの出力を実現したいと考えています。

当初はimagesフォルダをrootフォルダと同階層にコピーして実行することで解消していましたが、docsフォルダ内をさらにサブフォルダに分割したところ、imagesフォルダへの相対パスが深くなってしまったため、imagesフォルダのコピーでは手順が面倒になってしまった次第です。

### 知りたいこと

- Pandocでの生成時にドキュメントベースを指定できるようなオプションはないでしょうか？
- MarkdownからPDFへの変換は一度Latexにされるのですが、Latexのオプションでドキュメントベースを指定できるようなオプションはないでしょうか？
- Markdownファイル内の記述についてHTMLでも利用可能な共通的なパスの指定方法はありませんか？
- その他こうしたほうが良いなど

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Pandocでの生成時にドキュメントベースを指定できるようなオプションはないでしょうか？

こちら [Request for change: adding optione to define basepath・Issue #785](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/785) を読む限りでは、

```sh
$ (cd docs && pandoc doc1.md -o ../doc1.pdf -V documentclass=ltjarticle --latex-engine=lualatex)
```

などとするしかない様です。

その他には pandoc の `--filter` オプションを使う方法があります。

**filter.sh**

```sh
#!/bin/sh
sed -r 's:(../)+images/:./images/:g'
```

pandoc の内部では JSON 形式に変換したデータを扱っていますので `jq` コマンドなどを使うべきなのですが、ここでは簡便に `sed` コマンドを利用します。

```sh
$ pandoc docs/doc1.md --filter='./filter.sh' -o doc1.pdf -V documentclass=ltjarticle --latex-engine=lualatex
```

ただ、ご質問には `pandoc.exe` とありますので、Windows 環境で上記の処理が実行可能かどうかは不明です。

Comment: --filterオプションがあるのですね。環境はWindowsなのでshの実行はできないのですが、対処の方向性がわかりました。ありがとうございます！